# Powershell, SQL Server, SQLBULKCOPY: Importing NULL Values in .csv

Tags: powershell, null, sqlbulkcopy

I'm using a Powershell script found at ((https://blog.netnerds.net/2015/01/powershell-high-performance-techniques-for-importing-csv-to-sql-server/) to load data from quotes delimited, comma separated .csv in to a SQL Server (2016) database.

I've (for now) changed the Powershell script to use this line (KeepNulls instead of TableLock):

```
`$bulkcopy = New-Object Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy($connectionstring,([System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopyOptions]::KeepNulls))
`
```

I'm making an assumption that KeepNulls will populate a column in the SQL table with a NULL value if the corresponding field in the source .csv is empty:

`FirstName,Lastname`
`"Bruce","Foxton"`
`"Paul",""`
`"Johnny","Marr"`

So the copied,  row (2) in the SQL table, if KeepNulls behaves as I anticipate, should have a NULL value in the Lastname column. It doesn't, it's an empty string.

Does KeepNulls behave in a different manner than I'm expecting it to?

Also, how do I correctly configure SqlBulkCopy to use both KeepNulls and TableLock?

Comment: To answer the latter: `[System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopyOptions] "KeepNulls, TableLock"` will do. `KeepNulls` merely instructs `SqlBulkCopy` to respect `null` values, but empty strings are *not* `null` values. If you want to treat them as such, you'll need to modify the script to replace values obtained from reading the input, with something like `$line.Split($csvdelimiter).ForEach{if ($_.Length -eq 0) { [System.DBNull]::Value } else { $_ }}` (disclaimer: not tested, been a long time since I had to muck about with `DataTable`).

Comment: @JeroenMostert thanks for syntax for multiple SqlBulkCopyOptions. Yes, as per my question, I was wondering if empty strings would be treated as such.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Jeroen Mostert](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4137916/jeroen-mostert) has provided the crucial pointers in comments on the question; let me build on them:

- CSV data is inherently *untyped*, and PowerShell's [`Import-Csv`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/import-csv) and its in-memory counterpart, [`ConvertFrom-Csv`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertfrom-csv), treat all column values (fields) as *strings*, meaning that an *empty* field is represented as the *empty string* (`''`).

  - If you want to treat empty field as *database* `NULL`s, you'll need to test the input rows' properties for equaling `''` and replace their value with [`[DBNull]::Value`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.DBNull.Value)
  - You can do this with the help of the [intrinsic `psobject` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Intrinsic_Members#psobject) property PowerShell exposes on all objects is a rich source of reflection, notably via its `.Properties` collection.
  - See next section.
- PowerShell's handling [`System.Enum`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Enum)-derived types is very flexible in that it allows simple conversion of values to and from strings.

  - For flag-based enumerations such as [`SqlBulkCopyOptions`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopyOptions), you can simply specify the symbolic names of the flags in a *single string*, with the names separated by `,` (whitespace is ignored:

    ```bash
    # Shorthand for:
    #  [System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopyOptions]::KeepNulls -bor [System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopyOptions]::TableLock
    [System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopyOptions] 'KeepNulls, TableLock'
    ```

---

The following code (PSv5+) populates a [`DataTable`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Data.DataTable) instance from a CSV with matching column names, and replaces all empty CSV fields with `[DBNull]::Value`:

```bash
using namespace System.Data

# Create the data table that will serve as the copy source.
$dt = [DataTable]::new('source')
# Note that columns support NUL ([DBNull]::Value) values by default.
$dt.Columns.AddRange([DataColumn[]] (
  @{ ColumnName = 'FirstName'; DataType = [string] }, 
  @{ ColumnName = 'Lastname'; DataType = [string] }
))

# Populate the table from the input CSV and replace empty fields
# with [DBNull]::Value
# Note: A string literal with ConvertFrom-Csv is used here.
#       In your real code, use Import-Csv with a file path.
@'
FirstName,Lastname
"Bruce","Foxton"
"Paul",""
"Johnny","Marr"
'@ | 
  ConvertFrom-Csv |
  ForEach-Object {
    $dr = $dt.NewRow()
    foreach ($p in $_.psobject.Properties) {
      $dr[$p.Name] = if ('' -eq $p.Value) { [DbNull]::Value } else { $p.Value }
    }
    $dt.Rows.Add($dr)
  }
```

You should then be able to use `$dt` as the data source in [`SqlBulkCopy.WriteToServer`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy.WriteToServer) calls.

Comment: Thanks for this! The syntax for SqlBulkCopyOptions is most useful.